How can I compute probability of a simple predicate for 2-dim Normal distribution
The following code does not work:
Probability[
 mu0 + s * mu > 0 && mu0 + s * mu + s2 * xi < z * s2,
 {
  {xi, mu} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
  },
 Assumptions -> {s > 0, s2 > 0, z > 0}
]

How can I get an answer for the task?

What makes you think that there is a nice close-form solution?  If you specify all of the parameters and use NProbability, you'll get a result.

If {mu, mu0, s, s2} are intended to be the means and standard deviations of the joint distribution given, then Probability[  mu0 + s*mu > 0 && mu0 + s*mu + s2*xi < z*s2 /. {mu -> 0, mu0 -> 0, s -> 1, s2 -> 1}, {{xi, mu} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, Assumptions -> {z > 0}] evaluates to 0
